# How to get <img src="{% static "{{request_filename}}" %}" alt="My image"/> working

Tags: html, django, image

So Im passing a variable via views.py

```
return  render_to_response(html, {'file': file})
```

into my html

```
<img src="{% static "{{file}}" %}" alt="My image"/> working
```

However the file does not respond in my html. Can someone please help me.

Comment: like @GarethRees said, file is already available in the template tags scope so don't use parentheses also post your actual error. (html code)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
{% static "{{file}}" %}
```

just write

```
{% static file %}
```